# adding action to the c# datagridview left headerstyle column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I add `onClick` action to the left column which has a triangle and is a column added by default.
I found out how to hide it using `"RowHeadersVisible=false"` but I don't want to hide it I just want the `onClick` of that column to perform the same action as if you click on a different column in that same row.

Comment: I think It's WPF, it's a DataGridView that I placed inside a UserControl.cs in C# .NET for a VSTO Add-In

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it's the action

```
private void datagrid1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.ColumnIndex == -1)
    {
    }
}
```